# what does a recursive closure returns to?

Tags: javascript, recursion, closures

I want to write a function (persistence) that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit.
For example:

```
persistence(39) === 3 // because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4=4
                      // and 4 has only one digit

persistence(999) === 4 // because 9*9*9 = 729, 7*2*9 = 126,
                       // 1*2*6 = 12, and finally 1*2 = 2

persistence(4) === 0 // because 4 is already a one-digit number
```

I wrote this:

```
function persistence(num) {
   //code me
   var f;
   f= countPersistence(num);
   var toReturn= f(num); console.log("received value: "+toReturn);
   return toReturn;
}

function countPersistence(num){
  var count=0;
  return function g(num){
    var numt=num+"";
    numt=numt.split("");
    if(numt.length>1){
      count++;
      for(var i=0; i<numt.length-1; i++){
        numt[i+1]=numt[i]*numt[i+1];
      }
      arguments.callee(numt[numt.length-1]);
    }
    else 
      { console.log("returned value: "+count); return count;}
  }

}
```

As you can see running this code, the returned value of the inner function is not exactly what expected. 
Indeed, a function should return to where it is called from, right?. But in this case since it's recursive it is called from itself.
I have no idea how to retrieve the actual value (without using global variable)

Comment: FYI: arguments.callee is deprecated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not return a value when you call your inner function recursively. You could fix it like this (removing the `else` block and making it common code), so that always the last updated value of `count` is returned:

```js
function persistence(num) {
   //code me
   var f;
   f= countPersistence(num);
   var toReturn= f(num); 
   return toReturn;
}

function countPersistence(num){
  var count=0;
  return function g(num){
    var numt=num+"";
    numt=numt.split("");
    if(numt.length>1){
      count++;
      for(var i=0; i<numt.length-1; i++){
        numt[i+1]=numt[i]*numt[i+1];
      }
      arguments.callee(numt[numt.length-1]);
    }
    return count;
  }
}

console.log(persistence(39)); // 3
console.log(persistence(999)); // 4
console.log(persistence(4));  // 0
```

But `arguments.callee` is deprecated, and moreover you are making things overly complicated with nested functions.

You can do it like this:

```js
function persistence(num){
  return num < 10 ? 0
       : 1 + persistence(String(num).split('').reduce((a, b) => a*b));
}

console.log(persistence(39)); // 3
console.log(persistence(999)); // 4
console.log(persistence(4)); // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning on the recursion line

```
return arguments.callee(numt[numt.length-1]);
```

and as I stated in the comments arguments.callee is deprecated so you should use the function name.

```
return g(numt[numt.length-1]);
```